# Efficient way to find the index of repeated sequence in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large list of numbers in python, and I want to write a function that finds sections of the list where the same number is repeated more than n times. For example, if n is 3 then my function should return the following results for the following examples:

> When applied to example = [1,2,1,1,1,1,2,3] the function should return [(2,6)], because example[2:6] is a sequence containing all the same value.
>
> When applied to example = [0,0,0,7,3,2,2,2,2,1] the function should return [(0,3), (5,9)] because both example[0:3] and example[5:9] contain repeated sequences of the same value.
>
> When applied to example = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2] the function should return [] because there is no sequence of three or more elements that are all the same number.

I know I could write a bunch of loops to get what I want, but that seems kind of inefficient, and I was wondering if there was an easier option to obtain what I wanted.

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried with.

Comment: What you actually want to find is the *slice parameters* where sections of the list repeat, not the indices. You'd be off by one.

Comment: The second example is either wrong or the definition of n is wrong. There are 3 zeroes at the start and so the zero is not repeated *more than n times*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby` and `enumerate`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> n = 3
>>> x = [1,2,1,1,1,1,2,3] 
>>> grouped = (list(g) for _,g in groupby(enumerate(x), lambda t:t[1]))
>>> [(g[0][0], g[-1][0] + 1) for g in grouped if len(g) >= n]
[(2, 6)]
>>> x = [0,0,0,7,3,2,2,2,2,1]
>>> grouped = (list(g) for _,g in groupby(enumerate(x), lambda t:t[1]))
>>> [(g[0][0], g[-1][0] + 1) for g in grouped if len(g) >= n]
[(0, 3), (5, 9)]
```

To understand groupby: just realize that each iteration returns the value of the key, which is used to group the elements of the iterable, along with a new lazy-iterable that will iterate over the group.

```
>>> list(groupby(enumerate(x), lambda t:t[1]))
[(0, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fc90a707bd0>), (7, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fc90a707ad0>), (3, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fc90a707950>), (2, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fc90a707c10>), (1, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fc90a707c50>)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a lot more efficient than what I was doing. I'd like to understand how this exactly works though. I get what enumerate(x) and the key function do, but what exactly does groupby return? Why do we need the second half and not the first? After that function is called I start to get lost.

Comment: Neat one. Probably most efficient if you need all the groups, but I wonder if it won't be slower if you don't need all subsequences at once and would  be satisfied with generator of them.

Comment: @FilipMalczak If I understand you correctly, then this is easily achieved by replacing the list comprehension at the end yet another generator expression.

Comment: Yeah, basically, but the whole groupby(...) is executed before the comprehension. I guess you could wrap it in another generator used in comprehension or even inline it. I was just wondering if some solution that would yield each subsequence as soon as it is found wouldn't be a bit faster.

Comment: @FilipMalczak Yeah, this must be doing two passes over the list, but if you wrap it in a generator you can squeeze the last bit of efficiency out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single loop by following the current algorithm:

```
def find_pairs (array, n):
    result_pairs = []
    prev = idx = 0
    count = 1
    for i in range (0, len(array)):
        if(i > 0):
            if(array[i] == prev):
                count += 1
            else:
                if(count >= n):
                    result_pairs.append((idx, i))
                else:
                    prev = array[i]
                    idx = i
                count = 1
        else:
            prev = array[i]
            idx = i
    return result_pairs
```

And you call the function like this: `find_pairs(list, n)`. The is the most efficient way you can perform this task, as it has complexity O(len(array)). I think is pretty simple to understand, but if you have any doubts just ask.

Comment: This is a good answer that presents the "classic" imperative programming techniques. That being said, you should fix your indentation.

Comment: This answer will not work if the sequence ends at the end of the array. Tthe algorithm as it is right now will detect no difference to the previous element and will not jump into the else block.

It will also count incorrectly if there are two monotonous subsequences back to back. In this case, it will start counting one index too late in the latter subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this. Note that your question is ambiguous as to the role of n. I assume here that a series of *n* equal values should be matched. If it should have at least *n+1* values, then replace `>=` by `>`:

```
def monotoneRanges(a, n):
    idx = [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if not i or a[i-1] != v] + [len(a)]
    return [r for r in zip(idx, idx[1:]) if r[1] >= r[0]+n]

# example call
res = monotoneRanges([0,0,0,7,3,2,2,2,2,1], 3)

print(res)
```

Outputs:

```
[(0, 3), (5, 9)]
```

Comment: Nice, but you need to deal with an edge-case: `monotoneRanges([0,0,0,7,3,2,2,2,2,1,0], 3)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks for noticing that. I think I fixed it with the added `not i` condition.